# How many solutions does $\int_{0}^{x}{\sin (\sin t)dt} = 0$ have?

Tags: integration, area

Source: MAT $2012$ 
How many solutions for $0< x \le 2\pi$ does the following integral have?
$$\int_{0}^{x}{\sin (\sin t)dt} = 0$$
How would this curve look like, and how do I go about visualising a curve such as this? It doesn't seem to be a normal sin curve. My goal is to somehow visualise this and get the signed areas to be equal to each other. I do not have any experience with questions like these, nor do I know if or how this function can be integrated. So while trying this question, the only thing that came to my mind was drawing the curve. I am unable to think of any other approaches besides this.

Comment: If your goal is to visualize "the curve" (of the integrand), [use for instance Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+sin%28sin+x%29). If it is to solve your exercise, please edit your post to [include *some* work](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @AnneBauval I am not sure what work to show here. The path to a solution is straightforward. Visualise the graph, set x such that signed areas are equal. The only place where I could show "work" is in the visualisation of the curve, which I cannot(hence the question).

Comment: @AnneBauval I realise that I can use a graphing calculator. I want to do it without one.

Comment: The "work to show" is: your attempts to solve your exercise without plotting the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first find the zeros:
$$\sin(sin(t))=1 \Rightarrow sin(t)=\alpha\cdot\pi$$
since $-1\leq\alpha\cdot\pi\leq1\rightarrow\alpha=0$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$\alpha=0$$
$$\sin(t)=0$$
$$t=\alpha\cdot\pi$$
and since this function makes sense for all $x\in[0,2\pi]$

statement 1: $$\sin(\sin(t+\pi))=-\sin(t)$$
proof:
$$\sin(\sin(t+\pi))=\sin(-\sin(t))=-\sin(\sin(t))$$
now,
$$\sin(\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}))=\sin(1)>0$$
so:
$$\forall t\in[0,\pi]:\sin(\sin(t))>0$$
which tells us that:
$$\forall x>y\in[0,\pi]:\int_x^y\sin(\sin(t))dt>0$$
now, let's say that:
$$\int_0^x \sin(\sin(t))dt=0$$
that means that $x\notin(0,\pi]$ (that would mean that the integral is bigger than $1$), but $x=0$ is a solution

so if $x\in(\pi,2\pi)$, that would mean that:
$$0=\int_0^xf(t)dt=\int_0^{x-\pi}f(t)dt+\int_{x-\pi}^\pi f(t)dt+\int_\pi^x f(t)dt$$
set $u=t-\pi$ on the last integral
$$0=\int_0^{x-\pi}f(t)dt+\int_{x-\pi}^\pi f(t)dt+\int_0^{x-\pi} f(u+\pi)du=\int_0^{x-\pi}f(t)dt+\int_0^{x-\pi} -f(u)du+\int_{x-\pi}^\pi f(t)dt=\int_0^{x-\pi}f(t)dt-\int_0^{x-\pi} f(u)du+\int_{x-\pi}^\pi f(t)dt=\int_{x-\pi}^\pi f(t)dt>0$$
the last $>$ was because $\pi,x-\pi\in[0,\pi]$

unless of course $\pi=x-\pi$ and then the condition is true

so the solutions are: $x\in \left\{ 0,2\pi\right\}$

Comment: Imo, this question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, better encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: @AnneBauval but I clicked on the button "post answer" and not "improve question"

Comment: I understand. The way to "encourage the person who posted the question to improve it" is to comment under the question. If you don't have enough reputation (=50) yet to comment any post, better avoid low-quality posts, and answer better ones.

Comment: @AnneBauval what do you mean by "low quality"?

Comment: By "low quality", we mean: not meeting this site guidelines. For more details, follow the link in my first comment to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\sin(\sin(t)) \ dt$$
By the Fundamental Theorem,
$$f'(x) = \sin(\sin(x))$$
If we solve $f'(x) = 0$ over $x \in (0,2\pi]$ we have that $x = \pi, 2\pi$. This means $f(x)$ has two turning points. We know that $f(0) = 0$ if we extend the definition naturally to $x \in [0,2\pi]$ and we know $f(x)$ is increasing from $0$ as $\sin(\sin(t))$ starts positive. At $x = \pi$ it must reach a maximum and at $x = 2\pi$ it must reach a minimum. Using the substitution $u = \pi - t$, we have
$$f(2\pi) = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(\sin(t)) \ dt = -\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}\sin(\sin(\pi-u)) \ du = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(\sin(u)) \ du$$
As $\sin(\sin(u))$ is odd, $f(2\pi) = 0$. By the reasoning earlier there must be only one solution in $x \in (0,2\pi]$, namely, $x = 2\pi$.

Comment: Imo, this question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, better encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.